# web application architecture

Tags: architecture

We have an existing app which is mostly JSP based for front end and Java/DAO based back end connecting to an oracle DB. This is an enterprise level trading application.

Recently our management gave directive to use GWT to have a more modern look and feel to our front end pages. So we have migrated a few existing pages to GWT as well as all brand new development is in GWT. GWT is being used for both rendering front end as well as server side communications and AJAX.

However, I am concerned about fully embracing GWT as it is a client side architecture where most of the rendering logic processing happens on the client side.

1. Is my concern justified?
2. What other architectures would you recommend? Spring MVC/Webflow? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with a service architecture.  Keep the processing in the back so you can swap UIs in and out without rewriting the back end.

They can be SOAP or REST.  You need not make them heavy.

Best to not depend on JSP or GWT for the processing.  Ever hope to make this available on iPad?  It'd be good to be able to do it without rewriting the whole thing.

Start with coarse-grained services that match your use cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my concern justified?

No.

Doing less work on the server means doing more requests per second.

Comment: So you agree with me; and my concern is justified then?

Comment: @rationalSpring: No.  Your concern is not justified.  Google focuses on very scalable architectures.  That's why GWT is popular.